# XlsxWriter object save as http response to create download in Django

Tags: python, django, excel, httpresponse, xlsxwriter

XlsxWriter object save as http response to create download in Django?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I think you're asking about how to create an excel file in memory using `xlsxwriter` and return it via `HttpResponse`. Here's an example:

```
try:
    import cStringIO as StringIO
except ImportError:
    import StringIO

from django.http import HttpResponse

from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook


def your_view(request):
    # your view logic here

    # create a workbook in memory
    output = StringIO.StringIO()

    book = Workbook(output)
    sheet = book.add_worksheet('test')       
    sheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello, world!')
    book.close()

    # construct response
    output.seek(0)
    response = HttpResponse(output.read(), mimetype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=test.xlsx"
    
    return response
```

Comment: That's nice. If you get some time could you flesh it out into an example program that I could add to the XlsxWriter [examples](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/tree/master/examples).

Comment: Sure, will do. By the way, strictly speaking, xlsxwriter doesn't really stores the workbook in memory - it uses `tempfile.tempdir` internally - this cause problems on google app engine: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014055/using-xlsxwriter-in-google-app-engine-for-python?lq=1.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that other post. That is what brought me here. `:-)` A fully in-memory file assembly without access to a directory would be tricky but probably doable. I'll put it up high on the TODO list.

Comment: @jmcnamara, I've sent you a [pull request](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/pull/24). See what else should I include in it, thanks.

Comment: why are you using 0,0 and then the actual content? any logic, please explalin

Comment: @Clayton `0, 0` specifies the cell, in this case A1.

Comment: does not work. __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype' on line: response = HttpResponse(output.read(), mimetype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")

Answer (score 87):

A little update on @alecxe response for Python 3 (**io.BytesIO** instead of **StringIO.StringIO**) and Django >= 1.5 (**content_type** instead of **mimetype**), with the fully in-memory file assembly that has since been implemented by @jmcnamara (**{'in_memory': True}**) !
Here is the full example :

```
import io

from django.http.response import HttpResponse

from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook


def your_view(request):

    output = io.BytesIO()

    workbook = Workbook(output, {'in_memory': True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello, world!')
    workbook.close()

    output.seek(0)

    response = HttpResponse(output.read(), content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=test.xlsx"

    output.close()

    return response
```

Comment: God bless you for this answer

Comment: **Heads Up**: xlsxwriter builds the file using temporary filesystem files, so the reader may find it confusing that using `in_memory` [actually uses StringIO](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/xlsxwriter/packager.py#L159). However, the final file output is determined by the first parameter to `Workbook()`. If it's a string, a file with that name is created (_even if `in_memory` is used_). If it's a StringIO, the final file will be stored in memory. 
[The text in this example helped](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_http_server.html)

Comment: Also, it might be good to close `output`. I don't think it's _necessary_, but its good practice for memory management. [In the StringIO docs they demonstrate closing the object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.StringIO).

Comment: you are godsend

Answer (score 22):

When it comes to Django, you can even do without the whole `StringIO` shenanigans. `HttpResponse` behaves just like a StringIO in that respect:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

def your_view(request):
    # your view logic here

    # create the HttpResponse object ...
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=test.xlsx"

    # .. and pass it into the XLSXWriter
    book = Workbook(response, {'in_memory': True})
    sheet = book.add_worksheet('test')       
    sheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello, world!')
    book.close()

    return response
```

Addendum: You need to specify `{'in_memory': True}` or you might get `HttpResponse has no attribute seek()`. Thanks @Jeb

Comment: I tried (Python 2.7) and it fires 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'seek' error anyway.

Comment: latest Django version?

Comment: nope - I had to use 1.7.7 - sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Hey @Radek, I just tried it with your environment: Python2.7 and Django-1.7.7 and -1.7.11 - both worked like a charm. Maybe, if possible, try upgrading your environment? According to djangoproject.com 1.7 is insecure AND no longer supported anyways.

Comment: Hi @nutz, Django 1.7 is unsupported, indeed. However sometimes you get the version to work with without ability to immediate upgrade :( The env is Python 2.7.9, Django 1.7.7, experienced on Windows 10.

Comment: Anyway I believe your approach is right and should be followed by anyone reading this and only knowing that such error might be experienced in some outdated config.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. (using django 1.9 / python 3.5)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. Using Django 1.9.11 and Python 2.7.11

Comment: Using Python 3, Django 3, and DRF. It's working perfectly fine.

Comment: This is the only working answer for me as of Django 3.1.6. The other answers just produce a document with the text object [Object]

Answer (score 1):

It's better to follow the official doc from [jmcnamara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10238/jmcnamara) (package developer)

[Example: Simple Django class](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_django_simple.html)

Answer (score 1):

I use nodejs with `reportProgress: True`. My Django code is like this;

```
output = io.BytesIO()
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'in_memory': True})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write(y, x, column_name)
worksheet.write(y, x, column_name)

workbook.close()
output.seek(0)
return FileResponse(output.read(), filename="reservations.xlsx")
```

If you do this then you can use like this

[image: image loaded]

Answer (score 0):

A simple Django View class to write an Excel file using the XlsxWriter module.

```
import io
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
import xlsxwriter


def get_simple_table_data():
    # Simulate a more complex table read.
    return [[1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9]]


class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request):

        # Create an in-memory output file for the new workbook.
        output = io.BytesIO()

        # Even though the final file will be in memory the module uses temp
        # files during assembly for efficiency. To avoid this on servers that
        # don't allow temp files, for example the Google APP Engine, set the
        # 'in_memory' Workbook() constructor option as shown in the docs.
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

        # Get some data to write to the spreadsheet.
        data = get_simple_table_data()

        # Write some test data.
        for row_num, columns in enumerate(data):
            for col_num, cell_data in enumerate(columns):
                worksheet.write(row_num, col_num, cell_data)

        # Close the workbook before sending the data.
        workbook.close()

        # Rewind the buffer.
        output.seek(0)

        # Set up the Http response.
        filename = 'django_simple.xlsx'
        response = HttpResponse(
            output,
            content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        )
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename

        return response
```