# Using xlsxwriter in Google App Engine for Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xlsxwriter

I am wondering if anyone knows how to use xlsxwriter in Google App Engine for Python.  The documentation only shows how to open,write and save to a file.  I've looked at workarounds using StringIO for other Excel libraries, but they don't seem transferable to xlsxwriter.  The main reason seems to be that in other libraries you can supply a StringIO buffer, whereas in xlsxwriter you can only supply a string for the name of the file.

I have a basic solution in place using pyexcelerator but xlsxwriter is so much more feature rich that I'd like to use it, if possible.

Comment: Have you seen : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393242/xlsxwriter-object-save-as-http-response-to-create-download-in-django

Comment: Just an FYI, that doesn't work on Google App-Engine because it xlsxwriter tries to save things to a temp directory.

Comment: Update: Version >= 0.4.8 of XlsxWriter works with the Google App Engine. See [this example](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_headers_footers.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently developed a project on App Engine using python & xlsxwriter.
I face a similar issue, and I found a better workaround which *doesn't require extra code and works as running on the local system*.

We can use the [tmp environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#filesystem) - **a runtime filesystem** in App Engine which exists in the life span of a request/task queue.

while creating a writer object pass the `/tmp/file` as shown below,

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/tmp/my_file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
#
# perform your operations
#
writer.save()
```

In the subsequent code, you can read the same file and perform desired operations, like send it in the mail or upload it somewhere like...

```
file_path = '/tmp/'+ filename
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    my_file_data = f.read()
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

UPD: the [issue](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/28) was fixed by the xlsxwriter author (works since 0.4.8 version). See the [example](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_http_server.html).

---

Relying on my answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393242/xlsxwriter-object-save-as-http-response-to-create-download-in-django), here's what should work on GAE:

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

class IndexHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        book = Workbook(self.response.out)
        sheet = book.add_worksheet('test')
        sheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello, world!')
        book.close()

        # construct response
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/ms-excel'
        self.response.headers['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'Binary'
        self.response.headers['Content-disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="workbook.xls"'
```

But, it throws an error:

> NotImplementedError: Only tempfile.TemporaryFile is available for use

because `xlsxwriter` tries to write into the temp directory using `tempfile.tempdir` anyway, see [source](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/xlsxwriter/workbook.py#L349) of `_store_workbook` method. And, GAE doesn't allow `tempfile` module to be used in the project: see [source](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/dist/tempfile.py?r=233), because, as you know, no access to the disk there.

So, a "vicious circle" here. Probably you should think about modifying `_store_workbook` method to make it work completely in-memory. Or, may be you can `mock` `tempfile.tempdir` call on the fly and replace it with your own in-memory object.

Another option is to create an issue on `xlsxwriter` [issue tracker](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues), I bet @jmcnamara has some good ideas on the subject.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually started going to down the tempfile.tempdir rabbit hole, when I decided to post here.  I will definitely submit something to their issue tracker.

Comment: To solve the NotImplementedError, set the *cache* parameter during Api() create to None and it will disable the default file based cache.