# Xlsxwriter Error in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xlsxwriter

I am trying to use xlsxwriter in Google App Engine but I keep on getting the Error: 'Response' object has no attribute 'tell'. I have looked at previous questions [Using xlsxwriter in Google App Engine for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014055/using-xlsxwriter-in-google-app-engine-for-python#)
& [XlsxWriter object save as http response to create download in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393242/xlsxwriter-object-save-as-http-response-to-create-download-in-django) but I am still getting this error. I have tried to amend the example they give in the docs https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/examples/http_server_py2.py

I am currently using xlwt in GAE without any issues.

```
    output = StringIO.StringIO()

    # Even though the final file will be in memory the module uses temp
    # files during assembly for efficiency. To avoid this on servers that
    # don't allow temp files, for example the Google APP Engine, set the
    # 'in_memory' constructor option to True:
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(self.response.out,{'in_memory': True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    # Write some test data.
    worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello, world!')

    # Close the workbook before streaming the data.
    workbook.close()

    # Rewind the buffer.
    output.seek(0)

    # Construct a server response.

    self.response.headers['Content-disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test.xls'
    self.response.headers['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'Binary'
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] =  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

You are creating a StringIO , but you are not using it.  Your `xlsxwriter.Workbook(` should be using `output` not `self.response.out`

Secondly why are you doing `output.seek(0)`

After closing with workbook, you should be getting  the string from `output` and writing that out to `self.response`

And lastly if you are getting an error, it's always useful when asking a question to add the stacktrace to the question.  That way we can see which statement in your code is actually causing the exception to be raised.

Comment: Thanks I got it working by inserting self.response.out.write(output.getvalue())