# Django HttpResponse Excel

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I am trying to generate an excel file on Django site so I searched for it and look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393242/xlsxwriter-object-save-as-http-response-to-create-download-in-django). I write simply a function that writes what I need into an Excel file;

```
def create_excel(personal_information):

    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    book = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)

    sheet = book.add_worksheet()

    if personal_information['name']:
        sheet.write(1, 1,  personal_information['name'], text_format)

    book.close() 
    output.seek(0)

    return output
```

In my view.py;

```
def export(request):
    personal_information = json.loads(request.POST.get('personal_data'))

    output = create_excel(personal_information)
    response = HttpResponse(output.read(), content_type="application/ms-excel")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Excel.xls'

    return response
```

However, that gave "None". Do you have any idea to solve my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you `print output` before rendering the response? Is the output being formed properly? Also, is your `return response` statement indented properly? It doesn't appear to be in the question...

Comment: @rnevius Yes I cannot copy and paste the code properly but in my original code, there is no indentation problem. When I print the output before return it, it gives "<cStringIO.StringO object at 0x111c7bfb8>". And when I debug it, I can see the content of response that has some unknown figures.

Comment: Also I need to say that I am trying to get the excel file from a button in an pop-up window. I mean maybe I need to handle it ?

Comment: @waterkinq are you sure the `return response` is properly indented? What response do you see returned in the browser?

Comment: :) Here it is the return response when I look at from Google Chrome Network, I see such a response; "PKÖnHoÇT°[mxl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlQo0Çß÷),¿/p$@ªVU´=L¶v{vÀTÀÈvîÛÏ8 ....."

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
 in your function create_excel:

```
output      = io.BytesIO()
workbook    = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)
      .... your code .....
           at the end of your function
 # close workbook
workbook.close()
xlsx_data = output.getvalue()
return xlsx_data
```

in your view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; 
filename=your_template_name.xlsx'
    xlsx_data = create_excel()
    response.write(xlsx_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've a few solutions to this. I have a [demo project](https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/webproject) where I do this under the [`views.py`](https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/webproject/blob/master/mainapp/views.py) file. I use `openpyxl` but you can also use other libraries like `xlwings` if you need to keep macros (`.xlsm`).

Here is my code snippet:

```
def export_data(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Data.xlsx"'

    # create workbook
    wb = Workbook()
    sheet = wb.active

    # stylize header row
    # 'id','title', 'quantity','pub_date'

    c1 = sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1) 
    c1.value = "id"
    c1.font = Font(bold=True)

    c2 = sheet.cell(row= 1 , column = 2) 
    c2.value = "title"
    c2.font = Font(bold=True)

    c3 = sheet.cell(row= 1 , column = 3) 
    c3.value = "quantity"
    c3.font = Font(bold=True)

    c4 = sheet.cell(row= 1 , column = 4) 
    c4.value = "pub_date"
    c4.font = Font(bold=True)

    # export data to Excel
    rows = models.Data.objects.all().values_list('id','category', 'quantity','pub_date',)
    for row_num, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
        # row is just a tuple
        for col_num, value in enumerate(row):
            c5 = sheet.cell(row=row_num+1, column=col_num+1) 
            c5.value = value

    wb.save(response)

    return response
```